# Why cannot a breakpoint be set at this location?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

Please have a look at this screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA. Why is the breakpoint not valid in the middle line?

Comment: I don't see anything?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are setting breakpoint(s) while debugging. In that case, I think the running binary isn't matching the code--browser cache, swf/swc being picked from wrong location to name a few reasons to get into such situation.

Can you try hitting the third breakpoint (2nd valid one) and check if temp is showing correct value as you'd expect (the reason I think it would work is that temp is a local variable and hence its value should be available when swf/swc is actually executing that piece of code.